# Vector as Objects, push_back error - expected primary expression before "(" token

Tags: c++, object, vector, push-back

```
    for(int i = 0; i < classSize; i++){
    cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter Student Grade: ";
    cin >> grade;

    Student(name, grade);
    newMyClass.push_back(Student);
    cout << endl;
}
```

The newMyClass.push_back(student); gets an error - expected primary-expression before ")" token.
I would upload the entire code to give you a better understanding of the situation but it includes three supporting files as it is a object oriented program.

Comment: You need to provide a complete sample of code that illustrates your problem (i.e. that other people can compile, and get the same problem).  As you have described it, it is not clear whether `Student` is a class or a function, it is not clear what `newMyClass` is.   The reason for your problem will vary depending on what those things are.

Comment: Yea I figured that as well, its not really clear.. Sorry lol

Answer (score 1):

`Student` is a class name and not an instance of that class.

Just calling `Student(name, grade);` creates a class instance that is not named and thus cannot be used anywhere else; a Temporary/Anonymous variable.

When calling `newMyClass.push_back(Student);` is just syntactically wrong.

You need:

```
Student student(name, grade);
newMyClass.push_back(student);
```

Comment: or  `newMyClass.emplace_back(name,grade);` to cut out the middle man.

Comment: Precisely. I prefer that as well. Just didn't expose the underlying problem. :)

Comment: @bentank When I do this I get 'undefined reference to Student::Student(std::string,char)'